# NodeJs-MySQL SELECT not returning proper output

Tags: mysql, node.js

W3School tutorial on NodeJs-MySQL: SELECT cmmand does not provide output in proper format. In each row of output "RowDataPacket" word is appearing. How to avoid it?

```
C:\Users\Raju>node demo_db_select.js
[ RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'John', address: 'Highway 71' },
  RowDataPacket { id: 2, name: 'Peter', address: 'Lowstreet 4' },
```

---

I used the following code:

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "yourusername",
      password: "yourpassword",
      database: "mydb"
    });

    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = [ 
    RowDataPacket { id: 1, name: 'John', address: 'Highway 71' },
    RowDataPacket { id: 2, name: 'Peter', address: 'Lowstreet 4' }
]
```

This means the inside object is the instane of the class `RowDataPacket`. You can still simply use it like:

```
data[0].id // 1
data[0].name // John
data[1].name // Peter
```

Comment: How do I modify my code mentioned in my Question posted above (yesterday)

Comment: No modification as such. You just need to use it like I told you above i.e. `result[0].id`.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a MySQL query and storing the selected rows and columns in **result** variable. Actually result is a object. So run a for loop and print all the values as I written in code.

***Try this code:***

```
var mysql = require('mysql'); 
var con = mysql.createConnection({ host: "localhost", user: "yourusername", password: "yourpassword", database: "mydb" });
con.connect(function(err) { 
if (err) throw err;
con.query("SELECT * FROM customers", function (err, result, fields) { 
if (err) throw err;
for(let i in result){
    console.log("id="+result[i].id);
    console.log("Name="+result[i].name);
console.log("address="+result[i].address);
}
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code. "RowDataPAcket" is not appearing in output. However, I was expecting the result in the tabular form but I got  the result as below:

Comment: I tried your code. Now "RowDataPacket" is not appearing in the output. However, I go the output ,not in tabular form, but as below:Name=John
address=Highway 71

Comment: ID is also not appearing in each row?

Comment: When you execute a query on mysql console, then tabular format comes automatically. But here we are printing the value of variables on console, so it will not print in tabular format. By the way, what is need to print in tabular format? If you are making a webpage, then render it to webpage and the you can make a tabular format.

Comment: check your database if ID exist there or not?

Comment: ID exists in database. I will try to render it to web page and see teh rseults. Thanks.